# Mongoid: return embedded_in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How can I get name of the class of the object which embeds my instance:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :addresses
end

class Address
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :person
end

my_instance = Person.first.adresses.first
my_instance.embedded?
#=> true
my_instance.embedded_class????? # <=== I need to get this
#=> Person
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

```
my_instance.metadata.inverse_class_name.constantize
# or use the undocumented _parent method
my_instance._parent.class
```